# How to convert Figma project to Angular use Api?

Tags: angular, frontend, converters, figma

I am trying to convert figma to angular. I've tried but, finding it hard to implement. Any resources or suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: As I understand you have figma designs and you now want to build them using angular? The first step would be create an angular project following the angular docs. The second step would be trying to generate a figma export in html/css which can be used in the angular project (search for plugins to help with this). Once you've got a base up and running I'd suggest posting any exact issues you have here alongside code samples

Answer (score 0):

You can import the figma design file into Desech Studio. This will not be 100% pixel perfect, but it will be a good start. After further adjustments you can integrate with the angular plugin to export angular code.

Check [this github repo](https://github.com/desech/studio-angular) to see more details on the angular plugin

Answer (score 0):

[Figmular](https://www.figmular.com/) claims to provide similar functionality, but I haven't tried it personally yet. Just applied to join the beta.